# from a 4d array (3D coordinates + a binary marker) 3D plot only points marked '1'

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I would like to identify certain regions on a 3D plot. For simplicity I will give the example of a sphere (but my goals is for arbitrary data): Having defined points on a sphere via

```
Table[If[i^2 + j^2 + z^2 <= 1, 1, 0], {i, -2, 2, 0.1}, {j, -2, 2, 
  0.1}, {z, -2, 2, 0.1}]
```

I wish to plot all points marked with a 1 (in this case a sphere) on a 3D graph. This is a simple example, but in general I will have data similar to the above: a 1 for a point I wish to mark on a 3D plot, zero for a point I don't.

What would be the best way to make such a graphic?

One idea so far is: I scan the data for points marked with 1 (as opposed to 0) and create an entry in a new array {ip,jp,kp}, where these are the coordinates of the point marked by 1. I then proceed to use ListPointPlot3D[] for the new array created. Not exactly sure how to implement this in practice however... or if there is a more elegant way..

Answer (score 3):

```
table = Table[If[i^2 + j^2 + z^2 <= 1, 1, 0], {i, -2, 2, 0.1}, {j, -2, 2, 
    0.1}, {z, -2, 2, 0.1}];
```

If you want to get the 3D coordinates from positions of `1` in `table` you can use `Position`

```
coords1 = Position[table, 1];

ListPointPlot3D[coords1, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can make `table` a  `SparseArray` and use the property `"NonzeroPositions"`:

```
coords2 = SparseArray[table]["NonzeroPositions"];

coords1 == coords2
```

> True

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `1` and `0` to mark your selected points, you could instead directly generate the point triple that satisfies your condition, and use `Nothing` otherwise. For example:

```
ListPointPlot3D[Flatten[Table[If[i^2 + j^2 + z^2 <= 1, {i, j, z}, Nothing],
                              {i, -2, 2, 0.1}, {j, -2, 2, 0.1}, {z, -2, 2, 0.1}], 2], 
                BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image: points within a ball]

Here, `Flatten[]` tidies everything up at the end so that only a list of triples is passed to `ListPointPlot3D[]`.

Answer (score 2):

`Pick` might help. Also, here a way to perform everything a bit more efficiently (because this uses packed arrays).

```
pts = Tuples[ConstantArray[Subdivide[-2., 2., 40], 3]];
boole = UnitStep@Subtract[1., Dot[pts^2, ConstantArray[1., 3]]];
Graphics3D[Point[Pick[pts, boole, 1]]]
```

This uses the coordinates from the list `pts` to place the points in $\mathbb{R}^3$. If you prefer to plot the integer positions, you can use, well, `Position` (and `ArrayReshape`):

```
Graphics3D[Point[Position[ArrayReshape[boole, {41, 41, 41}], 1]]]
```

The you input tensor, this work without `ArrayReshape`:

```
boole2 = Table[
   If[i^2 + j^2 + z^2 <= 1, 1, 0], 
   {i, -2, 2, 0.1}, {j, -2, 2, 0.1}, {z, -2, 2, 0.1}];
Graphics3D[Point[Position[boole2, 1]]]
```

Comment: Here's another way to generate `pts`: `pts = Flatten[CoordinateBoundsArray[ConstantArray[{-2., 2.}, 3], Into[40]], 2]`; this also produces a packed array.

Comment: Wow, `CoordinateBoundsArray` is part of the language since 2015 and I haven't heard about it, yet. oO And `Into` is not even documented. Interesting.  Thank you!  And I hope you are well!

Comment: Yes, it's really nifty for generating an nD grid of points. I'm swamped with a lot of stuff, but I am more or less okay. Thanks for the well-wishes.